# PHP DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string when the year is three digit number

Tags: php, symfony, datetime

I have a Symfony controller that receives a request from the client-side and has to parse the date that comes in (e.g. *12-12-2004*) to the DateTime object and store it in the DB. It works perfectly, except when I try to input a date that has a three digit year in it, for example:

> DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (12-12-940) at position 7 (4): Unexpected character

The code itself is very simple, i just call `new /DateTime` on the value that comes from request from the client-side.

Comment: So use 4 digits year standard, what's the problem with it?

Comment: It works if you make `940` into `0940`

Comment: @RiggsFolly the problem is I cannot send 0940 because this is send from a datepicker value and the datepicker will always trim the leading zeros

Comment: Just be aware the for mysql, the supported date range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html  If you really need old dates then you will need a different approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTime`'s constructor can't handle years with three digits. One possible solution is to use [`setDate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.setdate.php) somehow like this:

```
$dateString = "12-12-940";
list($day, $month, $year) = explode('-', $dateString);

$date = new DateTime();
$date->setDate($year, $month, $day);
```

Answer (score 3):

The error message tells you everything. DateTime expected the Year as a four digit Number. If your year has only three digits, you have to add padding zero's. `new \DateTime("12-12-0940");` works perfectly.

To pad a string, you could use `str_pad`

```
$padded_year str_pad($year, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

You could also combine this code with array_map to split and join an date string to a correct padded date string like so

```
$date = "2-2-940";
$date = join('-', array_map(function($number, $padding) {
    return str_pad($number, $padding, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}, explode('-', $date), [2,2,4]));
```